# Are LoadRunner questions on topic on SQA or on Stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support

On one hand, "Software Quality Assurance & Testing" seems to suggest that LoadRunner questions belong here:

> [–§–](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  Software Quality Assurance & Testing Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for software quality control experts, automation engineers, and software testers.

On the other hand, the site is up for 4 years but there isn't a "LoadRunner" [tag](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/tags) here. Also, there are [9 ~LoadRunner questions](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=loadrunner%20is%3Aquestion) and [1 ~Vugen question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/search?q=vugen%20is%3Aquestion) here, as compared to [526 ~Loadrunner questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=loadrunner%20is%3Aquestion) and [~93 Vugen questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vugen%20is%3Aquestion) on Stackoverflow.

Should LoadRunner questions be asked on SQA or on Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your citation is clear, those questions are welcome here. LoadRunner definitely falls under the criteria of a QA program, which we support.

One thing to note about tags is that if a question has a tag, but is the only question carrying that tag for a period of time, the tag dies. So for a tag to live you need a higher rep user to spawn the tag plus another question to keep the tag alive.

But the lack of a tag doesn't mean it isn't welcome here.